# UIImagePickerController's view with wrong size

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using a `UIImagePickerController`'s `UIView` as a sub-view of my own `UIViewController's` `UIView` subview. Nothing special in that, the problem comes when I take a picture. What is happening is something like this:

1 The picture I am seeing from the `UIImagePickerController`'s view is something like this:

[image]

2 This is what I see when I take the picture (`[self.imagePicker takePicture];`
) and put it on a `UIImageView`:

[image]

From what I see the image that comes out is a bit higher in the Y axis. Is there any way to solve this? I don't care if I have to use some sort of cropping with the image that comes out in the:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
```

---

I may understand this behaviour as I am using `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` on the `UIImageView` `contentMode`, but I would like to be able to specify the Y from where I want to start to "look" at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was able to figure this out 28 minutes after, oh well, here it goes:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageTaken CGImage], CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 960.0f, 960.0f));

[selectedImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

By cropping at `960.0f` I am able to keep the original quality of the picture and also able to tell from which `Y` I am able to "cut" it from. I also added this:

```
+ (UIImage*)rotate:(UIImage*)image andOrientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

    CGContextRef context=(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    if (orientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, 90/180*M_PI) ;
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, -90/180*M_PI);
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        // NOTHING
    } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, 90/180*M_PI);
    }

    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    UIImage *img=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

Because the picture is coming rotated to the left.